# Function with callback doesn't retrieve result out of my HTTP POST call

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, variables

I want to make a **REST call and get the result out in a variable** (*access_token*). My variable AFAIK is global. Why is my variable access_token undefined at the end, even though i get a result in the console ? I understand that this call is async, but I put a 'false' in the call.

```
var https = require('https'),
querystring = require('querystring');

require('request-to-curl');
// First, get access token

var postData = querystring.stringify({
    'grant_type': 'password',
    'username':'<myusername>',
    'password':'<mypassword>'
});

var options = {
    hostname: 'myserver.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/v1/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': postData.length
    }
};
    function postVal(options, value) {
 //var responseObject;
 var access_token;

    var responseObject;
    var req = https.request(options, function(res) 
    {
      res.setEncoding('utf-8');

      var responseString = '';

      res.on('data', function(data) {
        responseString += data;
      });

      res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(responseString);
        responseObject = (JSON.parse(responseString));
       access_token = responseObject.access_token;
        console.log('console access:' + access_token);
        value(access_token);
       // return responseObject;
      });
    });
    req.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
      });
      // write data to request body 
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
}


 console.log("Access:"+ postVal(options, function(access) {
     console.log(access);
 }));
```

**Result**:

```
 $ node curl.js
    Access:undefined
    {"token_type":"Bearer","access_token":"f3DzDqW..dbMo0","refresh_token":"4jXqo4..kuuc2rMux3","scope":"global","access_token_type":"USER_GENERATED","note":"","expires_in":900}
    console access:f3DzDqWpnrgxnxt5vE42ih8ew..gOKyJY5dbMo0
    mlieber-ltm12:
```

Comment: https module doesn't accept a 3rd argument. See here https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback Thus you need to do this in the async way

Comment: thanks; removed my 3rd argument (_false_ ), but still the same thing.

Comment: You are attempting to examine `access_token` BEFORE it's value has been set.  I'm guessing you need to read a lot about asynchronous operations in node.js.  The ONLY place you can use the `access_token` value is in the `res.on('end', ...)` handler.   That's where you have to use it because that's the only place where you know it has finally been set.

Comment: ok, thanks; but ultimately i want to reuse this call multiple times. Ok so i changed the code to make it function, with a callback. Still not working, though ?